# openstack oslo messaging exception in nova-conductor

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have set up opensatck yoga in ubuntu 22.04.  I have gone through each verify step after install which all worked fine. I have 1x controller and 1x compute. In my controller i keep noticing this message.

```
==> /var/log/nova/nova-conductor.log <==
2022-11-28 08:35:58.338 76768 WARNING oslo_messaging._drivers.amqpdriver [req-9a1d29ba-756a-4a94-bef1-7c1caba6fb8d - - - - -] reply_284f5c12afcb4d0cb6504c70a01b458f doesn't exist, drop reply to 3357a913567c464fb48f7cfb47768a13: oslo_messaging.exceptions.MessageUndeliverable
2022-11-28 08:35:58.340 76768 ERROR oslo_messaging._drivers.amqpdriver [req-9a1d29ba-756a-4a94-bef1-7c1caba6fb8d - - - - -] The reply 3357a913567c464fb48f7cfb47768a13 failed to send after 60 seconds due to a missing queue (reply_284f5c12afcb4d0cb6504c70a01b458f). Abandoning...: oslo_messaging.exceptions.MessageUndeliverable
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this error.

this is my nova conf.

```
$ sudo egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/nova/nova.conf
[DEFAULT]
log_dir = /var/log/nova
lock_path = /var/lock/nova
state_path = /var/lib/nova
my_ip = 10.0.0.154
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:openstack@controller1:5672/
[api]
auth_strategy = keystone
[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller1/nova_api
[barbican]
[barbican_service_user]
[cache]
[cinder]
[compute]
[conductor]
[console]
[consoleauth]
[cors]
[cyborg]
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller1/nova
[devices]
[ephemeral_storage_encryption]
[filter_scheduler]
[glance]
api_servers = http://controller1:9292
[guestfs]
[healthcheck]
[hyperv]
[image_cache]
[ironic]
[key_manager]
[keystone]
[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://controller1:5000/
auth_url = http://controller1:5000/
memcached_servers = controller1:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = Default
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
username = nova
password = nova
[libvirt]
[metrics]
[mks]
[neutron]
auth_url = http://controller1:5000
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
region_name = RegionOne
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = neutron
service_metadata_proxy = true
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = METADATA_SECRET
[notifications]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/nova/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[oslo_reports]
[pci]
[placement]
region_name = RegionOne
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
auth_type = password
user_domain_name = Default
auth_url = http://controller1:5000/v3
username = placement
password = placement
[powervm]
[privsep]
[profiler]
[quota]
[rdp]
[remote_debug]
[scheduler]
[serial_console]
[service_user]
[spice]
[upgrade_levels]
[vault]
[vendordata_dynamic_auth]
[vmware]
[vnc]
enabled = true
server_listen = $my_ip
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
[workarounds]
[wsgi]
[zvm]
[cells]
enable = False
[os_region_name]
openstack =
```

Here is RabbitMQ status

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@controller1 ...
Basics

Cluster name: rabbit@controller1

Disk Nodes

rabbit@controller1

Running Nodes

rabbit@controller1

Versions

rabbit@controller1: RabbitMQ 3.9.13 on Erlang 24.2.1

Maintenance status

Node: rabbit@controller1, status: not under maintenance

Alarms

(none)

Network Partitions

(none)

Listeners

Node: rabbit@controller1, interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Node: rabbit@controller1, interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0

Feature flags

Flag: implicit_default_bindings, state: enabled
Flag: maintenance_mode_status, state: enabled
Flag: quorum_queue, state: enabled
Flag: stream_queue, state: enabled
Flag: user_limits, state: enabled
Flag: virtual_host_metadata, state: enabled
```

Here is policies

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_policies
Listing policies for vhost "/" ...
```

Here is permissions

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl list_permissions
Listing permissions for vhost "/" ...
user    configure   write   read
guest   .*  .*  .*
openstack   .*  .*  .*
```

I did a nova-conductor stop and then a start. the following is what gets logged

```
tail -f /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit*.log /var/log/nova/nova-*.log
```

https://pastebin.com/mCaM7S5a

this is the log after restarting rabbitmq

https://pastebin.com/uVrStC3M

There is no active firewall. the services are running on same server

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Comment: Is rabbitmq up and running (`rabbitmqctl cluster_status`). What does rabbitmq log when nova-conductor tries to connect? What do the policies look like? `rabbitmqctl list_polcies`, `rabbitmqctl list_permissions`.

Comment: @eblock I added that extra output and the logs

Comment: It tries to connect automatically, as you see in your output (`user 'openstack' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'`). Is there any firewall or apparmor blocking traffic? I would probably try a restart of rabbitmq and delete all queues just to be sure to have a fresh cluster. So either stop rabbitmq, drop the mnesia tables and start it back on. Then restart nova services just to make sure, and then see if there are any reply queues:`control01:~ # rabbitmqctl list_queues -p openstack | grep reply`

Comment: @eblock If i delete the queues. do they get created automatically? is there a series of steps i need to redo?

Comment: They are created automatically. Before you restart/delete anything, do you see reply queues right now?

Comment: I have managed to resolve it by reinstalling nova, neutron without ovn